# Add Team From startup event in liferay 6.2 ga4

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-hook

i'm currently  developing hook for user registration  (jsp , action ,startup action)
i wont at startup time (application.startup.events) to create 2 teams using this code
but isn't work

```
Team team=TeamLocalServiceUtil.createTeam(CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment());
    team.setCompanyId(companyId);
    team.setName("individual");
    team.setDescription("individual individual");
    TeamLocalServiceUtil.addTeam(team);
```

could any one help me

---

and I've inspected team table in database there are 2 fields (companyid and groupid ) i can't see what is difference between them   they are facing me any where  what their benefit and how i can find them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`companyId` is what the UI calls "instance". Most likely you have only one. The technical name `groupId` typically refers to the site that you create the team in.

I'd rather advise to create the team in a [single call](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/service/TeamLocalService.html#addTeam%28long,%20long,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
Team team = TeamLocalServiceUtil.addTeam(ownerId, groupId, name, description)
```

If this doesn't help, please update your question with more information than "doesn't work". You can be a lot more specific.

Answer (score 0):

`companyId` is the liferay portal instance id. If you setup liferay to be multi-tenant, this id is used to separate data between the virtual portal.

`groupId` is organizational or site id.It's used if you want to separate your data between organization or sites.

try below code to add team :-

```
Team team=teamPersistence.create(CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment(Team.class.toString()));
team.setCompanyId(companyId);
team.setName("individual");
team.setDescription("individual individual");

teamPersistence.update(team);
```